# What's the difference between WLAN adapter address and host address?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, ip-address

When I connect to a WLAN, I can get a result as following through `ipconfig`:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
   IPv4 address . . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.83.237
   Subnet Mask  . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Wireless LAN adapter WLAN:
   IPv4 address . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.30.16.37
   Subnet Mask  . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
```

But when I use a python script to check the host IP of my computer, the result is different.
Codes:

```
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()
print("host: " + str(host))
host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
print("host ip: " + str(host_ip))
```

Results:

```
host: XQWE
host ip: 172.19.83.237
```

Here comes the question: when other computers try to connect to my computer (assuming that my computer is in the current WLAN, so as following), which IP address would be used? Ethernet adapter address or WLAN adapter address? What's the difference between them?

Moreover, if other computers want to use `socket` to connect with my computer's socket, which IP address of my computer would be used by them? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Ethernet adapter Ethernet** - This would generally be a physically connection using an Ethernet cable plugged into an Ethernet port on your computer.

**Wireless LAN adapter WLAN** - This would generally be a WiFi connection using a WiFi adapter in your computer.

You appear to be connected by both adapters to two different networks.  That means your PC is reachable by both networks, and which IP you'd use to reach your machine depends on which network the other device is a part of.

Answer (score 1):

> Ethernet adapter address or WLAN adapter address? What's the difference between them?

These are different interfaces on your computer which based on the values you show are also connected to different networks. Just compare this to a house which has multiple entrances which (in your case of different networks) open to different streets.

> ... when other computers try to connect to my computer (assuming that my computer is in the current WLAN, so as following), which IP address would be used?

If they explicitly specify the IP address of ethernet or WLAN as target for `connect`, then it will use the given IP address. If they specify instead the hostname, then it depends on how the name will be resolved to an IP address.

`gethostname` takes multiple sources into account when trying to find an IP address for a given hostname, i.e. local configuration like [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) or network wide name services like [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) or [WINS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Internet_Name_Service). `gethostname` on the remote system might return the same IP address as on your system, but it might also return a different one.

Comment: Thanks! So when other computers in other LANs try to connect to my computer, they need to know my hostname, and parse it to an IP address?

Comment: @yamato: Ultimately they need to know the IP address, because this is what they connect to. If you give them the hostname instead they need to resolve it before connecting with the mechanism I've described. Just imagine the hostname the name of a person you want to call and the IP address its phone number - at the end you call the phone number and if you were given the name you need to use your contacts or some directory service to get the phone number for the name.

Comment: Got it! Now my PC is in the WLAN, when other PCs want to connect to my PC through socket, their sockets will use my WLAN adapter address, right?

Comment: @yamato: it fully depends on what IP address they use to reach your system.